# GCLID ignored by Google Measurement Protocol, transaction (not set)

Tags: curl, google-analytics, measurement-protocol

I am at a loss here..

I use the Google Measurement Protocol to send (offline) conversions to Google Analytics with a simple cURL request:

```
$config['useragent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; rv:17.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/17.0';


$dataUrl = "v=1&t=pageview&tid=$ua&cid=$randomstring&dh=zonduurzaam.nl&dp=%2Freporting&dt=Zonduurzaam%20Reporting&ti=$requestid-n&ta=$affiliation&tr=$revenue&tt=$tax&ts=0&pa=purchase&gclid=$gclid";

$req = curl_init('https://www.google-analytics.com/collect');

curl_setopt_array($req, array(
    CURLOPT_POST            => TRUE,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER  => TRUE,
    CURLOPT_USERAGENT       => $config['useragent'],
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS      => $dataUrl

));
// Send the request
$response = curl_exec($req);
curl_close($req);
```

The transactions end up perfectly in Google Analytics but.. the Google Ads campaign data is always (not set) within Google Analytics.

When using https://ga-dev-tools.web.app/hit-builder/ to recreate the EXACT same hit, transaction data is connected to the correct Google Ads campaign.

I tried sending the hit as a transaction, as a pageview, nothing seems to work. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Try inserting the `gclid` parameter as querystring in the location (`dl`) parameter of the measurement protocol or in page (`dp`) parameter.

Comment: Unfortunately, neither dl or dp parameters are taking.